# How to access a custom property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have created a UserControl with a dependency property named **CustomLabel** of type String.

The control contains Label which should display the value of **CustomLabel** property.

I can do this in code using **OnLabelPropertyChanged** event handler:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Label",
        typeof(String),
        typeof(ProjectionControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("FLAT", OnLabelPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnLabelPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ((Label)FindName("myLabel")).Content = (string)GetValue("LabelProperty");
    }
}
```

I know there must be easier way in XAML, something like:

```
...
<Label Content="{Binding ...point to the Label property... }"/>
...
```

But I have tried many combinations (RelativeSource/Pah, Source/Path, x:Reference, just writing property name...) and nothing worked...

I am expert on WinForms and learning WPF for some thime, but these things are still alien to me.

Comment: You have to use a `{TemplateBinding}`. Post the full XAML of the control so I can tell you how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just bind to the `Label` property

```
<Label Content="{Binding Label}"/>
```

Also you may have to set the `DataContext` to the `UserControl` in your `xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication10.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             Name="UI"> // Set a name 

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}"> //Set DataContext using the name of the UserControl
        <Label Content="{Binding Label}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

## Full Example:

Code:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "Label", typeof(String),typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("FLAT"));

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication10.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             Name="UI">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks! The ElementName parameter and naming the user control did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, it's the right answer. But why does it have to be so complicated?